# Calculation with numpy, without iteration (vectorization)

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I would like to do calculation with python/numpy vectorization (without iteration) which results the values of the column "D". The calculated column "D" should have the same value as column "A" where the column "B" value first (as going down the list) equal or smaller than column "C" value.

On the first row where B <= C set D == A

```
| A | B | C | D
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 0
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0
| 0 | 0 | 2 | 1
| 2 | 4 | 3 | 0
| 0 | 0 | 4 | 2
| 3 | 5 | 4 | 0
| 0 | 0 | 6 | 3
```

Comment: Logic to me is unclear

Comment: On row 3, B is less than C. Therefore D should equal A. But on row 3, A equals 0 and D equals 1. Am I misunderstanding the rule, or is the table wrong?

Comment: To be sure of what you want, we like to see an iterative solution.  Usually it's easier to understand, or at least less ambiguous.

Comment: It's unclear to me too. The 5th and 7th rows also do not match the rule. Anyway, it this what you want? ```a[:,3] = np.where(a[:,1] <= a[:,2], a[:,0], a[:,3])```

Answer (score 0):

Unravelling the logic from the text and the results I think this is a summary

```
"""
Logic:
    if B > C:  D = 0

    The first time B <= C: D = A
    Subsequent times:
        D = previous D[ where B <= C] + 1 
"""
```

An implementation

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array( [ 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0 ])
b = np.array( [ 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0 ])
c = np.array( [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6 ])

tgt = np.array( [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3 ])

d = np.zeros_like( a )  # d == 0 unless changed

mask = b <= c
d[ mask ] = np.arange( len( d[ mask ] )) + a[ mask ][0]
# d[mask] = [ 0 1 ..              n ]    + first match in a 

d
# array([0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3])

d == tgt
# array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True])
```

Change the a array:

```
a = np.array( [ 1, 7, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0 ])
d[ mask ] = np.arange( len( d[mask])) + a[ mask ][0]

d
# array([ 0,  7,  8,  0,  9,  0, 10])
```

Comment: Brilliant, but it does not help SO if you answer an unclear question like this.